# Gradle build showing error when trying to add MapsActivity

Tags: android

I am making a project with parse starter kit for android and whenever I'm trying to add Google MapsActivity, gradle build is failing and showing the following errors

```
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

Error:(33) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':ParseStarterProject:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\RakeshS\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I have added compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
to gradle, changed minSdk from 9 to 14 but nothing's working. Please help

Comment: This error usually caused by mismatching of SDK version with support Library version. Please check your versions once .

Comment: just check min version minSDK 21 or higher and also check support library

Comment: I have checked the api's. 23 is installed and I have used maps in other projects where they work completely fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is showing you did not install Api 23. So either install API 23 or Change the appcompat version in your build.gradle file back to 22.2.1 (or whatever you have).

Comment: I have checked the api's. 23 is installed and I have used maps in other projects where they work completely fine.

Comment: are you using apache http client.?

Comment: Can you tell me how to change Map's api to v22 from v23? That is the problem I guess